# ios8 tableview no longer enters edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

When running the iOS 8 simulator one of my screens has stopped entering edit mode.  When pressing the button I created to active edit mode for the tableView nothing happens.  It still works in iOS8.

Has anything changed for tableview editing in iOS8 that I am un aware of?  Ive also noticed that when swiping to delete the row doesn't disappear like it use to.  What must be done to fix this problem?

Comment: What action you've set for the button that should enter in edit mode?

Comment: tableview setEditingMode: yes animated: yes